# How to solve ClassNotFoundException using Eclipse & Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

We have small team and we use Eclipse and Intellij IDEA.
We use Maven Modules too.

When Idea push some data to git and Eclipse pull data we have several problems.

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/epam/freelancer/business/context/ApplicationContext
at com.epam.freelancer.web.controller.FrontController.init(FrontController.java:38)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4944)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.epam.freelancer.business.context.ApplicationContext
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
... 13 more
```

This exception appear only in Eclipse not in Idea.
I spent more than 8 hours to solve this problem but nothing changed.

Project structure
parent - ***freelancer***
childs:
 ***database

 business

 security

 web*** - I deploy this module in Tomcat

Poms:
parent:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.epam</groupId>
<artifactId>freelancer</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Freelancer</name>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<modules>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>database</module>
    <module>business</module>
    <module>security</module>
</modules>
```

And modules poms
Web module

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.epam</groupId>
    <artifactId>freelancer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>web</name>

<build>
    <finalName>web</finalName>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam</groupId>
        <artifactId>security</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Security module

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.epam</groupId>
    <artifactId>freelancer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>security</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam</groupId>
        <artifactId>business</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Business module

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.epam</groupId>
    <artifactId>freelancer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>business</artifactId>
<build>
    <finalName>business</finalName>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.epam</groupId>
        <artifactId>database</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Java EE Module dependencies in Eclipse (Rightclick your dynamic web project, go to Properties > Deployment Assembly)

Answer (score 0):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.groupName</groupId>
    <artifactId>id</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent</relativePath>
</parent>
```

This is an example I had in a Maven child pom. The structure I used was:

 /common/parent/pom.xml

/common/child/pom.xml

And in my parent project I set the path to the modules like this:

```
<modules>
    <module>../childModule</module>
</modules>
```

I used NetBeans, but I hope it could be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `org.apache.catalina` dependency to your POM. Stacktrace looks like Maven can't find `Catalina`.